# MDN Nodejs/Express tutorial: how do I connect to the mlab database?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mlab

For reference, here's the tutorial: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Server-side/Express_Nodejs/mongoose

I have been following the nodejs/express tutorial on mdn but have been unable to complete this step (Connect to MongoDB) since I keep getting an authentication error.

After about an hour of research, I've realized that the problem may be due to incompatible shell versions; my shell is 3.6, while their's is 3.4.

How can I work around this?
Should I just quit and use a different db host (seems complicated tbh)? If so which do you recommend?

PS:I know that other possible causes of this error may be a)**passwords that contain special characters**, or b)using my username **instead of the db username** when connecting. 
However, I have taken the necessary steps to ensure that neither is the case.

Comment: If I were you, I'd use a local installation of MongoDB. It's not that hard to set it up and you will learn more by doing it yourself rather than using an external service.

Comment: Show us the code you are using for connecting

Comment: `var mongoose = require('mongoose');`
`var mongoDB = 'insert_your_database_url_here';
mongoose.connect(mongoDB, {
  useMongoClient: true
});`
`mongoose.Promise = global.Promise;`
`var db = mongoose.connection;`
`db.on('error', console.error.bind(console, 'MongoDB connection error:'))`

Comment: The mongo driver doesn't use the shell for connecting so incompatible shell versions shouldn't be an issue. Showing the code you're using and error would be helpful. I work for mLab and I'd recommend emailing support@mlab.com since we might be able to provide more in-depth support with authentication issues. We're always happy to help.

Comment: thanks for all the help. I eventually went with Ganev's suggestion and used a local installation

Answer (score 0):

Its pretty easy, mlab has user authentication on by default. just create a user with password and they have given the default connection strings on top.

secondly i user Studio3t, during connection creation i have an option **From URI** and **To URI** which makes it easier for me.

[image: mlab user management]